# Is it possible to get element by id from responsetext without printing it out first?

Tags: ajax

```
function somefunction()
{
var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
alert(xmlhttp.responseText.getElementById('someid').innerHTML);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","1.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

the response from xmlhttp is this

```
<p id="someid">100</p>
```

i need to get the "100" out from the id "someid"

tried using this

```
alert(xmlhttp.responseText.getElementById('someid').innerHTML);
```

but it doesn't work.

is there another way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jquery you can,

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "1.php",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(response) {
    alert($('#SomeID',response.d));
    alert($('#SomeID',$('<div/>').html(response.d)));
},
failure: function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```